# how to take the values from an input and a php array into a js and multiply?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok so as you can see in the code snip bellow I am creating choices (inputs) in number (1) in number (2) I display the choice's name and in number (3) I display the unit price.

(1) is a number from 1 to n, I want to take the input number from each (1) and multiply it with the unit price (3) (example x=(1)*(3)) and then sum all of these results and display them in another textbox.
I have tried several things but I couldn't make it happen.

I could really use some guidance here.

Any more information I will be happy to provide.

```
    <?php
        $sum = $choice['qty'] * $choice['timi'];
        foreach($choice3 as $choice3){
    ?>
    //(1)
<input type="number" class="colorqty" name="color[<?php echo $i; ?>][unit]" step="<?php echo $step; ?>" value="0" min="0" class="color_qty_1" onchange="updateTotal();">
 //(2)
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $choice3['price_name']; ?>" name="color[<?php echo $i; ?>][price_name]" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_2">
 //(3)
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $choice3['price']."€"; ?>" name="xrwmas" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_2" id="tests">  <br />
    <?php $i++;  }  ?>
```

for example from the loop above we get

[image]

I want to multiply in this example 5 * 68, 0 * 74, etc and then sum the results and display it in the sum box.

@Jerson is close but I it gets really messed up this is a bit of an edit on his code but still can't figure it out.

```
<input type="number" style="width:40px" class="colorqty" id="input_value" step="1" value="0" min="0" onchange="updateSum();">
 <input type="text" value="58" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_3" id="price">
 <br>
<input type="number" style="width:40px" class="colorqty" id="input_value" step="1" value="0" min="0" onchange="updateSum();">
 <input type="text" value="33" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_3" id="price">
<br> 
<input type="number" style="width:40px" class="colorqty" id="input_value" step="1" value="0" min="0" onchange="updateSum();">
 <input type="text" value="54" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_3" id="price">
<br> 
<input type="number" style="width:40px" class="colorqty" id="input_value" step="1" value="0" min="0" onchange="updateSum();">
 <input type="text" value="55" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_3" id="price">
<br>
<br><br>


<label for="sinolo" class="color_qty_2" style="margin-left:45px"> Σύνολο €</label>
                                     <input type="number" class="color_qty_2" style="background-color:white;color:black;width: 90px; border-color:black;border-radius:5px; border-width:1px; text-align:center;" value="<?php echo number_format((float)$sum, 2, '.', ''); ?>" id="a3" readonly="readonly">
```

and the js

```
 function updateSum(value,id) {
                                  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
                                    var input_val = 0;
                                    var price_val = 0;
                                    var some_test = 0;
                                    var test1 = 0;
                                    for(let i = 0 ; i < elements.length; i++) { 
                                        if(elements[i].getAttribute('id') == 'price') {
                                            
                                            price_val = parseInt(elements[i].value)
                                        }
                                        if(elements[i].getAttribute('id') == 'input_value') { 
                                            
                                            input_val = parseInt(elements[i].value)           
                                        }
                                        test1 = price_val*input_val;
                                        
                                        some_test += test1;
                                        document.getElementById('a3').value = some_test
                                    }

                                    }
```

Comment: you mean you want to multiply each value by loop count by the sum of loop count?

Comment: This php loop could create 5 different rows with the three values, what I want to do is multiply as mentioned above and then sum each. But I can't get it to work.

Comment: can you provide your desired output?

Comment: provide your desired ouput then i can analyze

Comment: @Jerson I added it in the description mate.

Comment: ohh ok do you mean after multiplying thus all item then sum it ?

Comment: please put all your code, is this a table with rows?

Comment: thats not a table rows

Comment: sidenote: only show the total on frontend for illustration purposes only. the real computation should be done server side

Comment: so I should post the input number multiply in php and then display with an echo?

Comment: @Jerson If you have the time check my comment below

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Is this a PHP, or a Javascript problem?

Comment: I wasn't sure on how to go with this if the best way was to go with php to solve it or js. I did solve it though. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did figure it out @Jerson helped out a lot.

So for the code in the beginning we add unique id in all items we need. In this example price and input so here is the example

```
<?php
        foreach($choice3 as $choice3){
    ?>
    //(1)
<input type="number" class="colorqty" name="color[<?php echo $i; ?>][unit]" step="<?php echo $step; ?>" value="0" min="0" class="color_qty_1" onchange="updateSum();" id="input_value_<?php echo $i; ?>">
 //(2)
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $choice3['price_name']; ?>" name="color[<?php echo $i; ?>][price_name]" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_2">
 //(3)
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $choice3['price']."€"; ?>" name="xrwmas" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_2" id="price_<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

Then we just need the JS that takes one element by class and counts its length and then well you as you can see makes it work for infinite inputs.

```
 function updateSum(value,id) {
 
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('colorqty').length;
    var input_val = 0;
    var price_val = 0;
    var multipl = 0;
    var output = 0;
    var i = 0;
    while(i < elements ) {
                        
        price_val = document.getElementById('price_'+[i]).value;
        input_val = document.getElementById('input_value_'+[i]).value;
        if(input_val != null){ 
        multipl = price_val*input_val;
        output += multipl ;
                        
        document.getElementById('a3').value = !Number.isNaN(output) ? output : 0
            }
          i ++;
          }
     }
```

and here is the working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnDos/kegb8p16/77/)

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me

```
        <?php Route::add('/route', function() { 

        $array = [
            [
            'price_name' => 'Xiaomi Poco X3',
            'price' => 2000
            ],
            [
            'price_name' => 'Xiaomi Poco F1 plus',
            'price' => 1500
            ],
            [
            'price_name' => 'Xiaomi Poco F1',
            'price' => 1000
            ]
            ];

            foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        ?>


        <div id="form">
            <input type="number" id="input_value" class="colorqty" name="color[<?php echo $key; ?>][unit]" value="0" min="0" class="color_qty_1" onkeyup="updateTotal();">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $value['price_name']; ?>" name="color[<?php echo $key; ?>][price_name]" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_2">
            <input type="text" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value['price']."€"; ?>" id="price" name="xrwmas" readonly="readonly" class="color_qty_2" id="tests">  <br />
        </div>


        <?php

        }

        echo '<p>SUM <span id="sum">0</span></p>';
        ?> 

        <script>

        function updateTotal(value,id) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input')

        var input_val = 0;
        var price_val = 0;

        for(let i = 0 ; i < elements.length; i++) {
            
            if(elements[i].getAttribute('id') == 'price') {
                
                price_val += parseInt(elements[i].value.replace('€',''))
            }

            if(elements[i].getAttribute('id') == 'input_value') {
            
                input_val += parseInt(elements[i].value)
            
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = !Number.isNaN(price_val * input_val) ? price_val * input_val : 0

        }

        </script>

        <?php

        }); 

        ?>
```

Will you need only javascript todo that

Comment: this could work but in the example above it sums 68,74,71,83 (296) and then multiplies the sum of 5,0,4,3=12 so it displays 3552 which would be incorrect, the correct number would be 68*5=340 | 74*0=0 | 71*4=284 | 83* 3=249 and should display 873

Comment: I edited a bit the js I added 'some_test +=(price_val*input_val); ' after the if and I changed the last document.getElementById('sum').value = !Number.isNaN(some_test) ? some_test : 0 but now I face the following problem, lets say that we do have four rows as in the example, if I add quantity to the first box everything is fine, if I add to the second box things get a bit messy in the example above if i have 0,0,0,1 the sum that appears is 1055